# set a data source in jboss standalone mode

Tags: java, jboss

I want to set a mysql data source in jboss standalone mode. I have already deploy the mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar and set the below data source configuration in standalone.xml under datasources

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</connection-url>
        <driver>mysql</driver>
        <security>
        <user-name>root</user-name>
        </security>
</datasource>
```

And when i click on the configured data source name in the web console im getting below error,

```
Internal server error{
"outcome" => "failed",
"failure-description" => "JBAS014739: No handler for read resource at address [
(\"subsystem\"=>"\datasource\"),
(\"data-source\"=>"\MySqlDS\"),
(\"statstics\"=>"\pool\"),
"],
"roleback" => "true"
}
```

I didnt add any thing to the  drivers section since it not nessaccary,

Below one is set to the sample data source set in jboss

```
<drivers>
      <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
      <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class
      </driver>
</drivers>
```

What i am missing here please?

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to specify driver class

```
 <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
```

Checkout this  link [How do I migrate my application from AS5 or AS6 to AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7)

Comment: do i need to have a xa-datasource-class also for mysql under drivers tag in standalone.xml? In the example data source they set for com.h2database.h2 it has set but do we need it in mysql too

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue under the same circumstances. The problem was that my AS didn't have the required module for PostgreSQL. Check in `jboss/modules/org` if you have a folder named `postgresql`. If not then create it. Then create a directory in it named `main`.
You then have to have two files present in there:

- PostgreSQL JDBC JAR
- module.xml configuration file

Download the JAR file according to the database you're using and copy it here. As for the `module.xml` just create a new file and set up the configuration. Mine looks like this, customize it for your case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgresql">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc4.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

Basically you just have to change the resource path to where your JAR file is.

*This is an issue with JBOSS, it doesn't warn you even though the JDBC driver is missing. I've wasted a ton of time finding this hidden bug :D*